# Echo problem when Bash script calls another Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I have a very simple Bash script that opens port 9999 using `nc.traditional` (since `nc` does not have the `-e` argument anymore) and then calls another Bash script using `nc.traditional`'s `-e` argument. The purpose of second script is to ask the *name* and *age* of the person who has connected to the Linux box on that port and just store these information in two separate files.

All works well except that I intend to turn off `echo`ing when one is entering his *age* and this right here is what causes failures and errors. To the best of my knowledge, it could be because of `file descriptors` or it could be something else that I'm not aware of.

Apparently using `-s` switch of `read` command does not work when the script is called by another script.

Using `stty -echo` in the second script causes "stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device" error to appear in the output of first script.

Also I would like to define a timeout for my prompt so that a user does not stall my resources. The `timeout` command also does not work when it is summoned by another script.

*First Bash script:*

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    nc.traditional -n -l -p 9999 -e ./NameAge.sh
    sleep 5
done
```

*Second Bash script:*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Please enter your name:"
read name
echo "name: $name" >> /tmp/name.txt
echo -n "Please enter your age:"
read age
echo "age: $age" >> /tmp/age.txt
```

I really appreciate if you could help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that you (the server) cannot control the terminal of the person connecting (the client), which is where you would need to turn off echoing to do what you want. I don't think there is an esay way arround this. You could respond with escape codes to clear the previous line, but that wouldn't have any effect until the user presses enter.

Comment: So, Should I just let go of it?
Also do you any idea about defining a timeout method for the second screen or that is not feasible as well?

Comment: @PoJam Unless you have control over what commands run on the client (like if your client has a companion script), there is no way to turn off echo (without hackery, that I know of). Timeouts, on the other hand are simple, use the timeout command (see manpage for timeout(1)). You will need to check the exit code to check if a command timed out. Something like `timeout read name || echo "waited too long..."`

Comment: Apparently timeout command also does not work when placed and called in the second script.

Comment: @PoJam right, sorry, read is a special bash built-in, so it can't be executed directly through timeout. You could still use timeout, just wrap read and anything using the variable created by read in a subshell, and use timeout for the entire subshell.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try your suggestion and update the thread.

Comment: Could not get it to work... could you please elaborate how to wrap everything with a timeout?